# powershell file system event watcher service

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I have a file transformation solution built upon powershell with filesystemwatcher and powershell noexit. The problem I have is that the events don't fire after a while (I have no idea when it stops, I just get a call from the production), and I'm not sure why that is. 
The question is basically if/how I can check health of existing active eventwatchers. I tried first by adding control if event object existed so that I could simply execute the powershell script a few times a day, but soon figured out it was powershell session bound and I was not able to fetch it from a new powershell session.

This is the basic structure of the solution. 
(Anonymized, so functions etc renamed a bit and the workload logics is stripped out and on the places where it says '...' it is not syntax error)

powershell.exe -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -inputformat none -File C:\|...|.ps1 WINDOWSTARTUP="hidden" WAITFORINPUT="NO" DOS="YES"

```
function Test-FileLock {
      param ([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Path)

  $oFile = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $Path

  if ((Test-Path -Path $Path) -eq $false)
  {
    return $false
  }

  try
  {
      $oStream = $oFile.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, [System.IO.FileShare]::None)
      if ($oStream)
      {
        $oStream.Close()
      }
      $false
  }
  catch
  {
    # file is locked by a process.
    return $true
  }
}

function ConvertType1($sourceFile, $custno, $destFile)
        {   
          $result = "-1" 
            try {                             

                $OFS = "`r`n"

                $data = ""

                $data += "..." 
                $data += $OFS + "`tType=""...""" 
                # |...|


                $data | Out-File $destFile
                $result = "Done"
                Write-Host $result
            }
            catch 
            {
                $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
                $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName 
                $result = "ConvertType1: " + $ErrorMessage + " - " + $FailedItem
                Write-Host $result
            }
            finally
            {
            }

            return $result         
        }

function ConvertType2($sourceFile, $custno, $destFile)
        {   
          $result = "-1" 
            try {                             

                $OFS = "`r`n"

                $data = ""

                $data += "..." 
                $data += $OFS + "`tType=""...""" 
                # |...|


                $data | Out-File $destFile
                $result = "Done"
                Write-Host $result
            }
            catch 
            {
                $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
                $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName 
                $result = "ConvertType2: " + $ErrorMessage + " - " + $FailedItem
                Write-Host $result
            }
            finally
            {
            }

            return $result         
        }


#$devTest = $true
$devTest = $false

if ($devTest)
{
    $logfile = "....LOG" 
    $monitorFolder = '\\..._transformation\Development\Test\In' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
    $destinationFolder = '\\..._transformation\Development\Test\Out' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
    $filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here.
}
else
{
    $logfile = ".....LOG" 
    $monitorFolder = '\\..._transformation\In' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
    $destinationFolder = '\\..._transformation\Out' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
    $filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here.
}



$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $monitorFolder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}



#Check if eventsubcriber already exists, if it does just terminate script. This way we can schedule this script continously to make sure we always have the watcher in place
#Added note: This does not work because the events are per session and we won't be able to see events from previous sessions. 
if($devTest)
{
    if(Get-EventSubscriber | Where-Object -Property SourceIdentifier -eq "devTest_...FileCreated") {
    Exit
    }
    Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier devTest_...FileCreated -Action {
    $sourceFilename = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $sourcePathFilename = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $sourcePath = split-path $sourcePathFilename
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    $destinationFile  = (join-path $destinationFolder  ([system.io.fileinfo]$sourceFilename).BaseName) + ".wli" 
    Write-Host "$logTime - The file '$sourcePathFilename' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
    try {
            $logTime = (Get-Date -format (Get-culture).DateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern) 
            Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -InputObject "$logTime - The file '$sourceFilename' was $changeType at $timeStamp"

    do {
        sleep -seconds 1
        $fileLockTest = Test-FileLock $sourcePathFilename        
    } while ($fileLockTest)


      switch ($sourceFilename.ToLower()) 
      { 
      {($_ -like "*hire*") -or ($_ -like "*change*")} { $result = ConvertType1 $sourcePathFilename 123456 $destinationFile  } 
      {($_ -like "*termination*") -or ($_ -like "*...*")} { $result = ConvertType2 $sourcePathFilename 123456 $destinationFile  } 



            default {$result = "Error. File name is not recognized. File name must |...|"}
        }


            Write-Host "$logTime - Transformation of file '$sourceFilename': $result"
            Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -InputObject "$logTime - Transformation of file '$sourceFilename': $result"
            Move-Item $sourcePathFilename (join-path $sourcePath "Backup")  -force
        }
        Catch 
        {
            $logTime = (Get-Date -format (Get-culture).DateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern) 
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName 
            Move-Item $sourcePathFilename (join-path $sourcePath "Error")  -force
            Write-Host "$logTime - The file '$sourceFilename' encountered an error during transformation. The error message was $ErrorMessage"  -fore red
            Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -InputObject "$logTime - The file '$sourceFilename' encountered an error during transformation. The error message was $ErrorMessage"
        }
    }
}
else
{
if(Get-EventSubscriber | Where-Object -Property SourceIdentifier -eq "...FileCreated") {
    Exit
    }
    Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier ...FileCreated -Action {
    $sourceFilename = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $sourcePathFilename = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $sourcePath = split-path $sourcePathFilename
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    $destinationFile  = (join-path $destinationFolder  ([system.io.fileinfo]$sourceFilename).BaseName) + ".wli" 
    Write-Host "$logTime - The file '$sourcePathFilename' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
    try {
            $logTime = (Get-Date -format (Get-culture).DateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern) 
            Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -InputObject "$logTime - The file '$sourceFilename' was $changeType at $timeStamp"

    do {
        sleep -seconds 1
        $fileLockTest = Test-FileLock $sourcePathFilename        
    } while ($fileLockTest)


      switch ($sourceFilename.ToLower()) 
      { 
      {($_ -like "*hire*") -or ($_ -like "*change*")} { $result = ConvertType1 $sourcePathFilename 123456 $destinationFile  } 
      {($_ -like "*termination*") -or ($_ -like "*...*")} { $result = ConvertType2 $sourcePathFilename 123456 $destinationFile  } 


            default {$result = "Error. File name is not recognized. File name must include information about type of file |...|"}
        }


            Write-Host "$logTime - Transformation of file '$sourceFilename': $result"
            Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -InputObject "$logTime - Transformation of file '$sourceFilename': $result"
            Move-Item $sourcePathFilename (join-path $sourcePath "Backup")  -force
        }
        Catch 
        {
            $logTime = (Get-Date -format (Get-culture).DateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern) 
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName 
            Move-Item $sourcePathFilename (join-path $sourcePath "Error")  -force
            Write-Host "$logTime - The file '$sourceFilename' encountered an error during transformation. The error message was $ErrorMessage"  -fore red
            Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -InputObject "$logTime - The file '$sourceFilename' encountered an error during transformation. The error message was $ErrorMessage"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain Session Bound. Are you not able to see Powershell running as a process? Or how it is ?

Comment: In the past I've seen filesystemwatchers fail due to error that are not handled. Have you check to make sure an error is not stopping further execution?

Comment: Perhaps bad explanation. With session bound I meant previously started powershell process and the eventsubscriber started with it.

Comment: Perhaps bad explanation. With session bound I meant previously started powershell process and the eventsubscriber started with it. But a Get-EventSubscriber will only list subscriptions started within the same powershell process, meaning I can't (to my knowledge) simply run the powershell script again and see subscriptions started via the previous powershell process. The actual powershell process of the previous startup is still active, but I need to somehow get the state of the eventsubscriber. Might be as that I have some unhandled exception somewhere that I need to look into instead. .